# Grab Amount from Specific String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to grab all amount from a string and then add them in java-script. My string can be,

```
"Discount 50GB + 1,000GB + Kit"
```

My string format is fixed, means the amount will be found just before GB. I just need to grab all these amount and then add them. So the result I will get is 50 + 1000 = 1050

Comment: Just wondering, are you generating this string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
var arr = "Discount 50GB + 1,000GB + Kit".split('GB')

var b = arr[0].replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
var c = arr[1].replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
total = parseInt(b, 10) + parseInt(c, 10);

alert(total);
```

**This will add every GB in your string** ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t00erz4z/)):

```
var sum = 0;

var arr = "Discount 50GB + 1,000GB + 7GB + 9GB hello 8GB Kit 10GB 10GB d".split('GB');
for (var i = 0 ; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
  var x= arr[i].replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
  var b = parseInt(x,10)

  sum += b;

}


alert(sum);
```

**You've mentionend in a comment below that there also could be 'Gb'. You can use this to get the result 'case insensitive' for 'GB' ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pyf9kbc9/))**

```
var sum = 0;
var search = "gb";
var regEx = new RegExp(search, "ig");
var replaceMask = "GB";

var result = 'Discount 50Gb + 1,000Gb + 7Gb + 9Gb hello 8gb Kit 10GB 10GB 5gb d'.replace(regEx, replaceMask);




var arr = result.split('GB');
for (var i = 0 ; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
  var x= arr[i].replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
  var b = parseInt(x,10)

  sum += b;

}


alert(sum);
```

Comment: There is problem. I don't know the number of GB in a string. You example assuming 2

Comment: Edited it, now you can have as many as GB you want in the string @user960567

Comment: YOur method will not work If I have "GB 1599: Instant Redemption B 100GB" Here I just need to grab 100 not GB 1599 because there is a space there.

Comment: That's true, but a) that was not your question and b) you will need a pattern that is matchable. It will be hard to figure it out with too many variable parameters

Answer (score 2):

Quick dirty one line style XD

```
var str = "Discount 50GB + 1,000GB + Kit";
str.replace(/[^\+\d]/g,'').split('+').reduce(function(a, b) { return (+a) + (+b) })
```

Explanation:

1. trim all characters that isn't digit or plus sign (`+`)
2. split the trimmed string with plus sign (`+`), thus we get array of number-like strings (and empty string)
3. in `reduce` method, convert number-like string to real number and sum up, whereas `+""` becomes number `0`.

---

EDIT: this is a liitle different from previous one.

```
var str = "Discount 50GB + 1,000GB + Kit + 60GB 80GB 10Gb";
str.replace(/[^\d\s]/g,'').split(/\s+/).reduce(function(a, b) { return (+a) + (+b) })
```

Explanation:

1. trim all characters that isn't digit or white space (word separater)
2. split the trimmed string with white space gaps (one or more continuous white spaces), thus we get array of number-like strings (and perhaps empty string)
3. in `reduce` method, convert number-like string to real number and sum up, whereas `+""` becomes number `0`.

To be more careful and guaranteed, your chosen answer is also good.

Comment: I don't know the number of GB in a string.

Comment: @user960567 I don't either. If the string contains number, this will give you the sum, if it doen't, you won't get anything. You could compose some random strings to test my RegExp.

Comment: test with this string "Discount 50GB + 1,000GB + Kit + 60GB  80GB 10Gb"

Comment: @user960567 This isn't the pattern you provide in your original question. I thought they were separated with `+` signs. So urh... could you provide more information about possible patterns?

Comment: The fixed format is that there will be GB before amount

Comment: @user960567 Updated. To be more careful and guaranteed, your chosen answer is also good.